# How to use recursion to add object into parent with known path

Tags: java

I have got some issue I cannot figure out. I am simulating filesystem with directories implemented by simple model `Directory.java`

```
public class Directory  {

    public Directory(String name, List<Directory> directory) {
        this.name = name;
        this.directory = directory;
    }

    private String name;

    private List<Directory> directory;
```

My problem is I have to add new dir into existing one with specified path (eg. test/test2/newdir). I was trying to use recursion, but it doesnt solve my problem, because when I changed the destination directory, root stayed unmodified. Can anybody help me please ?

Ondrej

EDIT: my recursive method

```
private static Directory _digIn(Directory dir, List<String> path, int depth) {
        if (depth < path.size()) {
            if (dir.getDirectory() != null) {
                for (Directory d : dir.getDirectory()) {
                    if (d.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(path.get(depth))) {
                        return _digIn(d, path, ++depth);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return dir;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This method returns me required dir, I am able add new dir into it but this change  is not reflected in root directory.

EDIT2: my insert method

```
public static void insertNewObject(Directory dirToSave, List<String> path) {
        Root root = getRoot(xmlFile);
        Directory dir = _digIn(root.toDir(), path, 0);
        if (dir.getDirectory() != null) {
            dir.getDirectory().add(dirToSave);
        } else {
            List<Directory> dirList = new ArrayList<>();
            dirList.add(dirToSave);
            dir.setDirectory(dirList);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show your recursive method.

Comment: Somehow I don't see a single line of code here where anything is being added or modified.

Comment: Looks like you are editing the `Directory` instead of the `Root` element. Are you sure that when you edit `dir = root.toDir()` this also affects the `root` element? What does `root.toDir()` return?

Comment: `Root` element is only `Directory` element without name. It is because of inserting root into xml at the end of method. The point is, I am trying to replace something like `root.getDirectory().getDirectory().add(new Directory())` with resursive method. `root.toDir()` only transforms `Root` object into `Directory` object for recursion.

Comment: The recursion itself seems to wirk fine. Looks like the changes you do on the `Directory` you get from `root` are not saved in the `root` itself. Probably `root.toDir()` creates a new `Directory` object from your `root`, does it? If so, then the edits you do on this `Directory` are not reflected on the `root` as they are two different objects. You might consider a method to create a new `Root` from the `Directory`.

Comment: Yes, that's it, you are absolutely right. But how can I create a new `Root` from edited `Directory`, when I lost the previous directory context during recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you do the `root.toDir()` call you most likely create a **new** `Directory` which is a different object, so all the changes made on this `Directory` are not reflected in the `root`.

I'd propose two options to solve this:

**1.Make your `Root` hold the topmost `Directory`.**

```
    class Root{
        Directory rootDir;
        public Directory toDir(){
            return rootDir;
        }
    }
```

This will return you a reference to the `Directory` object stored inside `root`, so when you do your insert method this `Directory` will be altered and the changes will be reflected in the `root`

**2.Create a `Directory.createRoot()` method that will give you a new `root` element.**

In this case you can use your current `root.toDir()` method which will still return a topmost `Directory` (`dir`). After you call the insert method on it, just do a `root = dir.createRoot();` This is likely to give you a new `root` with most recent data about the directory structure.